# Why we use PrincipalAware in Struts 2

Tags: java, security, struts2

We are using `PrincipalAware` interface in our application to get some user related stuff.

I searched on the net to get the info about it with poor results, this is what I got on Google:

> **public interface PrincipalAware**
>
> Actions that want access to the Principal information from HttpServletRequest object should implement this interface.
>
> This interface is only relevant if the Action is used in a servlet environment. By using this interface you will not become tied to servlet environment.

Please, help me to understand it.

Comment: Which part you don't understand?

Comment: Where and why use it.

Comment: Q: Where? A: Action. Q: Why? A: To get principal information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `PrincipalAware` interface allows the Struts to inject a `PrincipalProxy` object into the action instance. This proxy can be used to get access to the servlet security mechanism. Like this

```
public class MyAction extends ActionSupport implements PrincipalAware {

  protected PrincipalProxy principal;

  public void setPrincipalProxy(PrincipalProxy principalProxy) {
    this.principal = principalProxy;
  }

  public PrincipalProxy getPrincipal() {
    return principal;
  }
}
```

Now, you can use `PrincipalProxy` in action method or on the view layer,

```
<s:if test="principal.isUserInRole('role1')">
```

Note, if you want to restrict an execution of some actions based on a role, then you could use `roles` interceptor.